# Asus UX305UA binding fn+f7 to a newly created event in acpi

Tags: shortcut-keys, acpi

I am trying to figuring this out. So on my laptop which is a asus ux305ua with an intal core i7-6500U quadcore processor and intel graphics with 8 gb of ram, I just installed ubuntu and managed to get the function keys working (even the brightness keys which needed to be linked).

However the issue I am having now is that there is no event in the acpi events folder for the fn+f7 keypress (turn of display) so I was planning on creating my own even. so if I run acpi_listen and press fn+f7 this is the output:

`video/displayoff DOFF 00000089 00000000 K
 PNP0C14:00 000000ff 00000000`

Hence here is the code I have written for the event:

```
event=video/displayoff DOFF 00000089
action=xset dpms force off
```

So I've just added this code to a new file in etc/acpi/events

However as you can guess this is not working after I restart the acpi service or reboot.

I am very new to ubuntu and couldn't find proper resources for this. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem here with a UX360UA (very similar)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

modify

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=native"
```

update

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot